# How to add a total column in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, sum, where-clause

I am trying to run some analysis on sales data using SQLite.

At the moment, my table has several columns including a `unique transaction ID`, `product name`, `quantity of that product` and `value of that product`.  For each transaction, there can be several records, because each distinct type of product in the basket has its own entry.

I would like to add two new columns to the table.  The first one would be a `total for each transaction ID` which summed up the total quantity of all products in that basket.

I realize that there would be duplication in the table, as the repeated transaction IDs would all have the total.  The second one would be similar but in value terms.

I unfortunately cannot do this by creating a new table with the values I want calculated in Excel, and then joining it to the original table, because there are too many records for Excel.

Is there a way to get SQL to do the equivalent of a `sumif` in Excel?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
select sum(qty) where uniqID = ...
```

But I am stumped by how to express that it needs to sum all quantities where the uniqID is the same as the one in that record.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't create a column like that in SQL. You would simply query for the total on the fly. If you really wanted a table-like object, you could create a view that held 2 columns; uniqID and the sum for that ID.

Let's set up some dummy data in a table; column a is your uniqID, b is the values you're summing.

```
create table tab1 (a int, b int);
insert into tab1 values (1,1);
insert into tab1 values (1,2);
insert into tab1 values (2,10);
insert into tab1 values (2,20);
```

Now you can do simple queries for individual uniqIDs like this:

```
select sum(b) from tab1 where a = 2;
30
```

Or sum for all uniqIDs (the 'group by' clause might be all you're groping for:)  :

```
select a, sum(b) from tab1 group by a;
1|3
2|30
```

Which could be wrapped as a view:

```
create view totals as select a, sum(b) from tab1 group by a;
select * from totals;
1|3
2|30
```

The view will update on the fly:

```
insert into tab1 values (2,30);
select * from totals;
1|3
2|60
```

In further queries, for analysis, you can use 'totals' just like you would a table.